# Python serial communication with Arduino, blinking the built-in led using an user input at the same time reading from the Arduino signal

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, blocking, led

I've been working for a school assignment which is needed to make a program to connect an arduino to read the arduino signal named 'Ping' and at the same time while reading an user input from the python file can switch the built-in led on and off. I have been working with this for 2 days searching on the internet for a solution?

Assignment 2: Read Ping from Arduino and switch a led on/off from your laptop.
Run the program “pingandled.ino” on your Arduino.
Using the tutorial https://petrimaki.com/2013/04/28/reading-arduino-serial-ports-in-windows-7/
Write a program (.py) Which reads the Ping from the serial bus and which simultaneously makes it
possible to switch on/off the default led (pin 13) on your Arduino from your PC.
If your program blocks reading the Pnigs when waiting for a command to switch the led on or off this is
incorrect. Reading the Pings should always continue!!!! Use the internet to find a solution.

We have got a arduino code which we are not allowed to change.

```
enter code here: int incomingByte = 0;
int ledPin = 13;

void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

int counter = 0;
void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
if (Serial.available() == 0 and counter == 0)
{
Serial.print("Ping");
delay(10);
counter++;
}
else
{
incomingByte = Serial.read();

// say what you got:
if (incomingByte == 49) { // ASCII printable characters: 49 means number 1
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
} else if (incomingByte == 48) { // ASCII printable characters: 48 means number 0
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}
delay(10);
if (counter < 100)
{
  counter ++;
}
else
{
  counter = 0;
}
}
}
```

I have a python code which has 2 functions, one for reading the arduino signal and one for switching the led on and off. If i call the functions seperately, it works but i need a code to do both functions at the same time in a while loop. The output is like: constantely printing the data from the arduino and while doing this I need to give an input, enter 1 or 0 to switch the led
ping

```
enter code here: import serial
import time
s = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600, timeout=0)
def blink():
data = s.readline()
data = data.decode()
print(data)
time.sleep(1)
def aan():
var = input()
var = var.encode()
var = s.write(var)

while 1:
```

Comment: To ask for someone to write the code for you might help you to finish the assignment quickly, to learn how to do yourself will benefit you for the rest of your life.

Comment: Hints: put the two program as two functions and call them in a while loop.

Comment: Mm, i already did that. I dont ask for the solution of my assignment, i want an answer for my question. Working two days on the same issue..

Comment: I dont ask for the answer of the assignment. I just want to know how to solve my issue. Working on the same issue over the past 2 days is hard.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I found the solution!! I have used Thread from library Threading.

python code:

import serial

import time

from threading import Thread

s = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600, timeout=0)

def blink():

while 1:

data = s.readline()

ping = data.decode()

print(ping)

time.sleep(1)

def aan():

while 1:

var = input()

s.write(var.encode())

if **name** == '**main**':

Thread(target = blink).start()

Thread(target = aan).start()